# why does tf.math.exp sometimes return values in float64 format?

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I write

```
tf.math.exp(2.0/20.0)
```

then I will get the result: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.105171>

but when I write

```
tf.math.exp(y[i]/20) #where y is a numpy array with float32 digits
```

I will get this :<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.9864462929738023>

why float 64 instead of float 32?

of course I can use tf.cast , I'm just wondering why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, inn TensorFlow, when you mix different types of numbers, like a `float32 and an integer (int64)`, TensorFlow promotes the result to the higher precision type, which is `float64`, to make sure you don't lose accuracy in your calculations. Hope this helps.!

In your case, I guess,  when you calculate `tf.math.exp(y[i]/20)`,

TensorFlow encounters `an element from your NumPy array y`, which is of type `float32`.

However, the `constant 20` is treated as a Python integer, which is of type `int64`

If you want to maintain the result as float32, you can explicitly cast the constant 20 to float32 like this:

```
tf.math.exp(y[i] / tf.constant(20.0, dtype=tf.float32))
```